# How to find an enum according to a value?

Tags: java, enums

I'm working with a (legacy, not changeable) enum that looks like this:

```
enum MsgEnum {
   private int number;
   private int msg;

   MSG_OK("OK", 0);
   MSG_NOK("NOK, 1);
   //lots of other messages

   private MsgEnum(String msg, int number) {
      this.msg = msg;
      this.number = number;
   }
}
```

If I have the `number`, how could I best find out which `MsgEnum` matches the number (assuming they are unique)?

Is there any better way apart from the following?

```
class MyEnumHelper() {

    public static MsgEnum MsgEnumfromNumber(int number) {
        for (MsgEnum m : MsgEnum.values()) {
            if (m.getNumber() == number) {
                return m;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Build a map from value to enum?

Comment: User either the suggested answer from Olivier.Roger or keep your for loop.

Comment: If the numbers are an arithmetic progression from 0 to N you can make use of the enum's ordinal: MyEnum.values()[number]. Otherwise the map suggestion is a good one

Comment: They start with 0 and count upwards, though some numbers are skipped in between.

Comment: Then map it is I guess :)

Comment: This is the way you do this type of thing in Java. Except, you don't need to make a helper class... you can put that static method in your enum itself. I usually call these methods "fromId" or "fromName", etc.

Comment: @GilMoshayof I disagree. This is **not** _the way you do this type of thing in Java_. This is the wrong approach. See the accepted answer.

Comment: for a finite iteration over 2 possible values? it's probably cheaper than holding a map in memory. If there were 100 possible values, I might agree with you. It's a matter of taste I suppose. I've always done it this way, and I've definitely never seen a map implementation for 2 values in an enum.

Comment: @GilMoshayof it's written "//lots of other messages" just behind the 2 enum values given as an example ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a static Map in your Helper and access it using a static method getMsgEnumFromInteger(int). Something like :

```
private static final Map<Integer, MsgEnum> INT_TO_ENUM = new HashMap<Integer, MsgEnum>();

static {
    for (MsgEnum msgE : MsgEnum.values) {
        INT_TO_ENUM.put(msgE.getNumber(), msgE);
    }
}

public static MsgEnum getByInt(int number) {
    return INT_TO_ENUM.get(number);
}
```

(sorry if there are errors, it don't have a Java env at the moment ^^ )

Comment: Sorry I should have written that the enum is in an external library that I want/have to use, but cannot change. That's what I meant with "legacy".

Comment: OK ^^ Then you can declare that static Map in your Helper :)

Comment: Could you give an example what you mean by static map?

Comment: Certainly the best approach, moving from on `O(n)` algorithm to an `O(1)` one. +1

Comment: technically speaking, this is still o(n), since he needs to iterate over the values once anyway. Altho it will save time in future calls, especially for a large amount of enum values.